# Received ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size when using sklearn RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When I was using `sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV` for hyperparameter tuning in this quite standard script

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

XGBModel = XGBRegressor(slient = False, n_jobs=7, n_estimators = 100)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    XGBModel, 
    param_distributions=params, 
    n_iter=param_comb, 
    scoring=make_scorer(mean_absolute_error, greater_is_better=False), 
    n_jobs=4, 
    cv=3, 
    verbose=1, 
    random_state=100)

random_search.fit(representations, targets)
```

I received `ValueError`

```
ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size
```

I ran this script on a slurm cluster, despite this `ValueError`, the script was still running normally, because the CPU usage was about 2800% on the compute node (4 times 7).

What does this `ValueError` mean? Will it affects the CV score?